# git pull in hooks/post-receive failed

Tags: git, githooks, git-pull, git-post-receive

On the server, /home/git/xxx/hooks/post-receive:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/xxx
git pull
```

On the server, /var/www/xxx was created like this:

```
cd /var/www
git clone /home/git/repositories/xxx.git
```

When I run "git push" on the client, got this message:

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you mention in the above, which one is the client and which one is the server? I'm confused!

Comment: Can you post the full output from `git push`? It's not clear if the error message is from an error on the client or an error on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, you want to automatically update a website when changes are pushed to a Git repository. Try this: http://www.ekynoxe.com/automated-deployment-on-remote-server-with-git/

Note that the website root directory (`/var/www/xxx`) is not a  Git repository itself; it just holds the working tree.

Comment: link is broken :-/

Answer (score 5):

As described [here](http://www.janosgyerik.com/deploying-new-releases-using-git-and-the-post-receive-hook/), the problem is that `GIT_DIR` is set to `.` when the hook is called.

If you unset `GIT_DIR` in the post-receive hook, it should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset GIT_DIR
cd /var/www/xxx
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the pulled directory,

```
cd /var/www
git clone /home/git/repositories/xxx.git
```

Above command will create a new directory under **/var/www**  as xxx, Provided your application name is xxx.

Now you need to go in this newly created directory like,

```
cd /var/www/xxx
```

Now run the command "git push". This should work.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself understood. My English is poor.

Comment: I have a git server which is the web server at the same time. The project under git's control is a website. I want every time I push changes from my working PC to the server, the website update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories folder should be bare repository.

```
git init --bare
```